# kotlin-dsl plugin Gradle : Dowload groovy

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Good morning,

In my company we are setting up a monorepository for the management of our different android libraries. My team is based on an implementation of the Now In Android app for dependency management. To simplify the creation of our libraries, we create our own Gradle plugins. These plugins are written with the help of Kotlin.

In my Android project I created a build-logic module at the root of the project.`I add my classes representing each of my plugins. In the build.gradle of this module I assign the kotlin dsl plugin to it:

```
plugins {
`kotlin-dsl`
}
```

Below I put you a complete image of the build-logic folder

[image: build-logic_folder]

We are behind a proxy so I configured in the settings.gradle.kts all access to our maven for dependency and plugin resolution.
This maven proxies to mavenCentral(), google() and gradlePlugin()

when I synchronize the project all the libraries download well, but the project goes into an infinite loop trying to download Groovy libraries.

[image: GroovyInfinite]

I checked well, the inquiry libraries are in gradle that I import.
I tested with version 7.5.1, 7.6 and 8.0

The download of groovy-something does not appear when I remove the kotlin-dsl plugin.

When I open the proxy locally, Android Studio downloads the dependencies from a gradle repository
[image: Download_prox_open]

Our company policy prevents us from opening the proxy to the outside on our build machines

Has anyone encountered this problem before and know how to fix it? I've been stuck on it for several days with no solution.

Thanking you

Comment: Have you tried configuring the proxy settings using [the JVM properties documented here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)?

Comment: Hello, yes and it work. The main problem are that our build machin for security reason do not have access to the outside. We have a custom maven to make the bridge but I did'nt find the distribution url of the repo.gradle